# How to fix my override equals() method

Tags: java, overriding, equals

• I'm writing a override method for .equals() to compare two different classes of shapes.

• The equals() will compare the dimensions of those shapes (EX: 4 X 4 X 4, equal to 4 X 4 X 4)

• Having trouble, already looked at other examples, and they don't apply to my program.

• Please help with the return statement and if I set up other parts of it, that would also help :)

By the way, I don't have the ability to use Eclipse.

Here's some code:

Method - My return statement is not done, I was trying to figure that out still.

```
   @Override
   public boolean equals( Object ob )
 {
    // instanceof is not in the AP Java subset
    if ( ! (ob instanceof Rectangle3) )
    {
        return false;
    }
    Rectangle3 that = (Rectangle3)ob;
    return Objects.equals()
    return t.getReal() == getReal() && t.getImag() == getImag();
 }
```

Rectangle class -

```
private int length;
private int width;
public Rectangle3(int l, int w)
{
    length = l;
    width = w;
}
public int getLength()
{
    return length;
}
public int getWidth()
{
    return width;
}

public String toString()
{
    return "(" + length + " X " + width + ")";
}
```

Box class -

```
 public class Box3 extends Rectangle3
 {
// instance variables 
private int height;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class box
 */
public Box3(int l, int w, int h)
{
    // call superclass
    super(l, w);
    // initialise instance variables
    height = h;
}
// return the height
public int getHeight()
{
    return height;
}
public String toString()
{
    return "(" + getLength() + " X " + getWidth() + " X " + height + ")";
}

}
```

Part of main -

```
public static void main(String []args)
{
    Rectangle3 one = new Rectangle3(5, 20);
    Box3       two = new Box3(5, 5, 5);
    Cube3    three = new Cube3(5, 5, 5);
    // print
    System.out.println("          Dimensions: ");
    showEffectBoth(one);
    showEffectBoth(two);
    showEffectBoth(three);
}

public static void showEffectBoth(Rectangle3 r)
{
    System.out.println(r.getClass().getName() + " - " + r);

}
```

Comment: Is a `Box` with the same dimension as a `Cube` equal to that `Cube`?

Comment: Is this the actual code you're using? You're calling methods on `Rectangle3` that don't appear to exist, like `getReal()` and `getImag()`

Comment: I got like a template of a override method, I'm not using those, no. Box and Cube are equal

Answer (score 0):

You've chosen wrong structure for inheritance of classes. The parent class should be `Box3`. `Rectangle3` is a `Box3` with height = 0; `Cube3` is `Box3` with equal sides:

```
class Box3{
    int length;
    int height;
    int width;

    Box3()
    {
    }

    Box3(int length, int height, int width)
    {
        this.length = length;
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
    }

}

class Rectangle3 extends Box3{
    Rectangle3(int length, int width)
    {
        super(length, 0, width);
    }
}

class Cube3 extends Box3{
    Cube3(int side)
    {
        super(side, side, side);
    }
}
```

And then you can add the following code to `Box3` class for comparing `Box3` instances:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object ob)
{
    if (ob == null) return false;
    if (ob == this) return true;
    if (!(ob instanceof Box3))return false;
    Box3 that = (Box3) ob;
    return that.getHeight() == this.getHeight()
        && that.getWidth() == this.getWidth()
        && that.getLength() == this.getLength();
}
```

You should also override `hashCode` method, something like this:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 1;
    hash = hash * 17 + this.length;
    hash = hash * 31 + this.width;
    hash = hash * 13 + this.height;
    return hash;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your existing equals method is slightly confusing, I will explain whats wrong with it in the last section, but theres a lot in there that is unclear.

### Writing an equals method.

An equals method is something which outputs true if two objects are equal **by whatever definition you choose**, so you have said that they need to both be rectangles and have the same class (Rectangle) and have equal dimentions. Here would be an equals method

```
public class Rectangle3{
    private int length;
    private int width;
    public Rectangle3(int l, int w)
    {
        length = l;
        width = w;
    }
    public int getLength()
    {
        return length;
    }
    public int getWidth()
    {
        return width;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other){
        if (!(other instanceof Rectangle3)){
             return false;
        }
        
        Rectangle3 otherRectangle=(Rectangle3)other;
        return this.length==otherRectangle.length && this.width==otherRectangle.width;
    
    }
}
```

Having seen Rectangle3 you should now be able to create one for Box3 as well.

## Overriding the hashcode

Remember that when you override the equals method you need to override the hashcode also; this is basically a quick check of equality. A hashcode **must** return the same number for two equal objects and should *probably* equal non equal numbers for non equal objects. An example might be as follows:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 37 * hash + this.length;
    hash = 37 * hash + this.width;
    return hash;
}
```

A good IDE will be able to ble to generate a new HashCode for you. Hashcodes are used by many collections (such as HashSet), failing to include it will cause you bugs down the road.

## Your equals method

```
   @Override
   public boolean equals( Object ob )
 {
    // this is good, first check if its the right type
    if ( ! (ob instanceof Rectangle3) )
    {
        return false;
    }

    //poor naming convention but again the right idea, we need to cast to Rectangle3 to use its methods
    Rectangle3 that = (Rectangle3)ob;
    return Objects.equals()

    //this just shouldn't be here, you've also missed a ;
    return Objects.equals()

    //t is not defined, possible you mean that, but in any case 
    //getReal() and getImag() are not defined in the rectangle class
    return t.getReal() == getReal() && t.getImag() == getImag();
 }
```

This is the equals method for **Rectangle3**, you'll need to create annother equals method for **Box3**, assuming Rectangle3's equals isn't suffificient (which it won't be as it doesn't include the 3rd dimention)